# Has the computed change of the axial tilt ever been measured?

Tags: earth, rotation, geology, io

Earth, the 3rd planet from the Sun, sometimes faces earthquakes and seaquakes that are so strong that they reportedly change the axial tilt and/or the rotation velocity. These changes are merely calculated, but have there also been some measurements/experiments that confirmed those calculations? If so, how did they measure it and due to which earth-/seaquake as the cause for the reported changes?

Since Jovian moon Io faces many ioquakes and eruptions too, I'd also like to know whether that happens on Io too and whether it was confirmed by some probe.

Comment: I suggest you do a very rough estimation of involved masses and displacement and show us the numbers so that we can discuss whether it is measurable

Comment: @a_donda I'm talking of the reported axis/rotation changes due to earth- and seaquakes. Rather seaquakes who on average are stronger.

Comment: Also: https://www.iers.org/IERS/EN/Science/EarthRotation/EarthRotation.html

Comment: can you link to reference that earthquakes change the *tilt*? Rotation is easy to calculate by simply considering moment of inertia and displacement of mass in terms of radial distance from the centre - and easy to measure with current atomic clocks; no entity can be measured with higher precision than time

Comment: It seems yes, both speed and tilt have been reported to change! See the wonderful answers to the following thee questions in Earth Science SE: [How are Earth's rotational changes due to large earthquakes calculated?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2583) and [Does the geographic North Pole move?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/7740) and [How are Earth's rotational changes due to large earthquakes calculated?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2583) I think a great answer can be written here and include references to these for support.